# Showing animation and restarting the game

Tags: java, android, animation

I am developing a turn based two player game.

What I want:- When someone wins, an animations pop ups and its shows player 1 or 2 wins. Then it waits for 2 sec after that the game restarts.

What I am getting:- The animation popups alright, it waits for 2 sec but after that the completed gameboard is shown ie the game is not restarted.

**animation.java**

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{
    // Take any action after completing the animation
    // check for fade in animation
    if (animation == ani)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
            //    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Thread.currentThread();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            finish();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

**gameboard.java**

```
public void winner(int x)
   {
                    int a=gameArray[x];

        Intent i = new Intent(this, animation.class);
        i.putExtra("winner", a);
        startActivity(i);

   }
```

What I tried and didn't worked:-

**gameboard.java**

```
public void winner(int x)
   {
                    int a=gameArray[x];

        Intent i = new Intent(this, animation.class);
        i.putExtra("winner", a);
        startActivity(i);
                    Thread.currentThread();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            finish();
                   Intent b= new Intent(this, gameboard.class);
                   startActivity(b);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

   }
```

While doing this the animation doesn't show at all, the game thread sleeps after any player wins. But after 2 secs the game is restarted.

I have drawn the gameboard using canvas.drawLine and in method named drawBoard(). What should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `Timer` class in the Android SDK. It is a specialized thread.  You could simply take the task that you are doing and implement it as `TimerTask` object. I have use this myself to run an animation engine. Review the API for the following method. Hope this helps!!!

```
Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html